# Is it possible to use an object in a nib as a sort of template for dynamically creating multiple new objects?

Tags: cocoa, webview

I would like to design an NSwindow with a WebView in IB for displaying popup links.  I need to be able to instantiate any number of these.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Typically, your window controller would subclass [NSWindowController](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
MyWindowController* controller = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowView"];

[controller showWindow];
```

In your nib, set the Owner to MyWindowController, then hook up your outlets as necessary.